# Javascript: Suppress "Stop running this script?", or how to use setTimeout?

Tags: javascript

I'm building a js library that reads binary files, including zip files.

Because there's no direct native support for arrays of binary data, when the zip files get large, there's a lot of copying that has to go on ([See my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919972/how-do-i-access-xhr-responsebody-from-javascript) for details).

This results in a "Stop Running this script?"  alert.   Now, I know this can happen if there's an infinite loop, but in my case, it's not an infinite loop.  It's not a bug in the program.  It just takes a loooooong time.

How can I suppress this?

Comment: Why are reading ZIP files in Javascript?

Comment: Why read zip files in Javascript?  Because I can. I wanted to see if it were possible, and so I'm building it. I can imagine some possible applications. Not sure how practical it will be. For now, it works, although for a 145kb file, it takes several seconds to unzip/uncompress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could divide the process into increments, then use `setTimeout` to add a small delay.

Comment: A delay isn't neccesary — even a timeout of zero will allow a return to the event loop and should reset the warning.

Answer (score 4):

This message is for security reason enabled, because otherwise you could simply block the users browser with a simple never ending loop. I think there no way to deactivate it.

Think about splitting you processing into serval parts, and schedule them via `setTimeout`, this should surpress the message, because the script is now not running all the time.

Comment: Thanks, I know *why* the message exists. I did use setTimeout() to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In IE (and maybe Firefox too), the message is based on the number of statements executed, not the running time. If you can split some of the processing into a separate function, and defer it with setTimeout, I believe that it won't count toward the limit.

Answer (score 2):

...answering my own question, so I could post the code I used.

The main issue was, I was reading the entire contents of a file, with a readToEnd() method, which actually reads one byte at a time.  When reading a large file, it took a looooong time.  The solution was to read asynchronously, and in batches.

This is the code I used:

```
readToEndAsync : function(callback) {
    _state = "";
    var slarge = "";
    var s = "";
    var txtrdr = this;

    var readBatchAsync = function() {
        var c = 0;
        var ch = txtrdr.readChar();
        while(ch != null) 
        {
            s += ch;c++;
            if(c > 1024) 
            {
                slarge += s;
                s = "";
                break;
            }
            ch = txtrdr.readChar();
        }
        if (ch!=null){
            setTimeout(readBatchAsync, 2);
        }
        else {
            callback(slarge+s);
        }
    };

    // kickoff
    readBatchAsync();
    return null;
},
```

And to call it:

```
textReader.readToEndAsync(function(out){
     say("The callback is complete");
     // the content is in "out"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this feature is specific to Firefox and/or other browsers, and it has nothing to do with the javascript language itself.

As far as I know you (the programmer) have no way of stopping it in your visitors' browser.