# How to download file via jQuery ajax and C#

Tags: c#, jquery, webmethod

I want to download a file using jQuery Ajax web method, but it's not working.

Here is my jQuery ajax call to web method:

```
function GenerateExcel() {
   var ResultTable = jQuery('<div/>').append(jQuery('<table/>').append($('.hDivBox').find('thead').clone()).append($('.bDiv').find('tbody').clone()));
   var list = [$(ResultTable).html()];
   var jsonText = JSON.stringify({ list: list });
   $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "GenerateMatrix.aspx/GenerateExcel",
          data: jsonText,
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (response) {

          },
          failure: function (response) {
               alert(response.d);
          }
            });
        }
```

and this is the web method definition:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
public static string GenerateExcel(List<string> list)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FileEName.xls");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(list[0]);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    return "";
}
```

How to get it done?

One more thing: I want to download it on client PC, not to save it on server.

Comment: What happens if you go to the link directly (without ajax)?

Comment: See these posts: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944241/ajax-request-to-download-an-excel-file-is-showing-me-truncated-response

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095102/how-do-i-load-binary-image-data-using-javascript-and-xmlhttprequest

Comment: @Lian i can't go to link directly because i have to send html from client side

Comment: You can have a look at that question that may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/9834261/1026611

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well i have done it using iframe

this is the modified ajax function call

```
 function GenerateExcel() {
            var ResultTable = jQuery('<div/>').append(jQuery('<table/>').append($('.hDivBox').find('thead').clone()).append($('.bDiv').find('tbody').clone()));
            var list = [$(ResultTable).html()];
            var jsonText = JSON.stringify({ list: list });
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "GenerateMatrix.aspx/GenerateExcel",
                data: jsonText,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    if (isNaN(response.d) == false) {
                        $('#iframe').attr('src', 'GenerateMatrix.aspx?ExcelReportId=' + response.d);
                        $('#iframe').load();
                    }
                    else {
                        alert(response.d);
                    }
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
        }
```

and this is the design part

```
 <iframe id="iframe" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

on Page load my code looks like this

```
 Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FileEName.xls");
 Response.Charset = "";
 Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
 Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
 Response.Write(tableHtml);
 Response.End();
```

Comment: Hi @rahul, your method is what I am looking for, but I got so confused with when the .hDivbox, b.Div, and table structure?  Is in the opener window?  I set the Iframe to display:block and did not anything. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

1. Add these in your view page-

   ```
   <iframe id="iframe" style="display:none;"></iframe>
   <button id="download_file">Download</button>
   ```
2. Server side

   ```
   public string Download(string file)        
   {

       string filePath = Server.MapPath(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileManagementPath"]);


       string actualFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(filePath, file);
       HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM";
       string filename = Path.GetFileName(actualFilePath);
       String Header = "Attachment; Filename=" + filename;
       HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", Header);           
       HttpContext.Response.WriteFile(actualFilePath);
       HttpContext.Response.End();
       return "";
   }
   ```
3. Add this code in your JavaScript

   ```
   <script>

       $('#download_file').click(function(){

           var path = 'e-payment_format.pdf';//name of the file
           $("#iframe").attr("src", "/FileCabinet/Download?file=" + path);

       });

    </script>
   ```

That should work!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the C# code responds with the correct headers for Excel, you can simply redirect to the link instead of using ajax:

```
var list = [$(ResultTable).html()];
var url = "GenerateMatrix.aspx/GenerateExcel";
var data = {list: list};
url += '?' + decodeURIComponent($.param(data));

// if url is an excel file, the browser will handle it (should show a download dialog)
window.location = url;
```

Comment: what about the web method it will remain same or not

Comment: I don't know anything about what your output is. check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/974079/setting-mime-type-for-excel-document

Comment: well i am using the same thing but ur answer is not working for me