# AJAX (or AJAX-esque) File Download

Tags: jquery, ajax, http, http-headers, download

This is a common question asked in various different ways, and I have collected some links below and explain why they don't work. I am looking for a full solution to the following.

In the web application I am developing there is a need for AJAX-esque file downloading with the following requirements

1. The user can click the link to download the file and without being directed to a new page, will receive a normal "Save as.." dialog we are all used to in web browsers for downloading files
2. If for some reason the server fails to serve up the file, a javascript callback should be called. Similarly, for if the server successfully serves up the file
3. Need to be able to modify the HTTP **request** headers to specify, for example, the *Content-Type* HTTP header in the request
4. Support across all A-grade browsers

**Things researched so far:**

a. [jquery.fileDownload](https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload) very elegantly solves requirements 1, 2 and 4 by using a combination of form submission, hidden iframes and having the server set a specific cookie. I am very familiar with this project (have contributed to it too). Requirement 3 is not supported though because HTML form submission and iframes (which this library uses) do not allow for specifying HTTP headers to the requested server resource. ([jdownloader](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jdownload/) also uses a similar iframe/form technique, but it also does not solve requirement 3).

b. It is possible to retrieve binary data from a file using XMLHttpRequest (with various hacks for the different browsers ([link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944241/ajax-request-to-download-an-excel-file-is-showing-me-truncated-response), [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095102/how-do-i-load-binary-image-data-using-javascript-and-xmlhttprequest), [link 3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data), [link 4](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Downloading_Files), [link 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919972/how-do-i-access-xhr-responsebody-for-binary-data-from-javascript-in-ie), [link 6](https://gist.github.com/hubgit/742267), [link 7](http://shasini.blogspot.co.il/2007/04/downloading-binary-streams-with.html), [link 8](http://web.archive.org/web/20071103070418/http://mgran.blogspot.com/2006/08/downloading-binary-streams-with.html)). But none of them cater for requirement 1. The binary data can be saved in a javascript variable, but there is no way to invoke the browser's "save as..." dialog to allow the user to save this binary data to a file on their hard drive

c. [This link](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/) (under the *"DOWNLOAD + SAVE FILES TO THE HTML5 FILE SYSTEM"* heading) has a full end-to-end solution using XHR2 and caters for requirements 1, 2 and 3. But it is badly supported (uses very new HTML5 FileWriter).

Any full solutions out there?

***EDIT***
We have some more options - which I plan to test. Perhaps the only option is to develop a library for this problem by collecting all hacks/solutions together in order to create a universal solution.

1. According to fibertech's solution below: use solution (b) above to save file into variable and then:

   For Internet Explorer: save this data using IE's execCommand()

   For others: use [data uris](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/data_URIs) ([link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833068/how-to-force-save-as-dialog-box-in-firefox-besides-changing-headers)) and the HTML5 *download* attribute of <a> tag to specify the name ([link 1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/a#attr-download), [link 2](http://codebits.glennjones.net/downloadattr/downloadattr.htm), [link 3](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Downloading-resources-in-HTML5-a-download), [link 4](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/a.download.html))
2. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916191/download-data-url-file) mentions something to do with using file download ability of canvas
3. [Downloadify](https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify) (and [this link](http://davidwalsh.name/downloadify) too)
4. A seemingly relevant [link](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/#toc-inlineworkers-bloburis) that has to do with web-workers but is doing something with Blob's and the [FileApi](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) to generate files.

Answer (score 0):

IE only solution:

```
function SaveContents(element) {
    if (typeof element == "string")
        element = document.getElementById(element);
    if (element) {
        if (document.execCommand) {
            var oWin = window.open("about:blank", "_blank");
            oWin.document.write(element.value);
            oWin.document.close();
            var success = oWin.document.execCommand('SaveAs', true, element.id)
            oWin.close();
            if (!success)
                alert("Sorry, your browser does not support this feature");
        }
    }
}
```

Required HTML sample:

```
<textarea id="myText"></textarea><br />
<button type="button" onclick="SaveContents('myText');">Save</button>
```

This will save the contents of the given textarea into a file with name equal to the ID of the textarea.

As for other browsers, you can read this: [Does execCommand SaveAs work in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833015/does-execcommand-saveas-work-in-firefox)

Test case and working example: http://jsfiddle.net/YhdSC/1/ (IE only..)

Comment: So would combining the solution from (b) in my original question with your IE technique and data URIs for other browsers solve the problem?