# Security error using CORS in IE10 with Node and Express

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, internet-explorer-10, cors

I'm constructing a Backbone application hosted on `http://example.com` which utilizes an API hosted on `https://api.example.com`. For the API, I'm using Node.js with the Express.js framework. My CORS solution seems to work in every major browser except IE (it even fails in IE10).

When a request is initiated from IE10, the request never hits the API server. As far as I can tell, the request is not even being sent. When I inspect the request using IE10's developer tools, both the request headers and response headers are blank. When a request is sent from *any* other browser, the request is received and a response is properly generated.

This is the error I see in the console:

```
SCRIPT 7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x4c7, The operation was canceled by the user.
```

The request uses jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  url: apiRoot + "/endpoint",
  success: function(response) {
    // Omitted irrelevant code
  }
});
```

According to [this](http://www.webdavsystem.com/ajax/programming/cross_origin_requests) article, CORS is disabled in IE by default and must be enabled:

> Internet Explorer ignores Access-Control-Allow headers and by default
>   prohibits cross-origin access for Internet Zone. To enable CORS go to
>   Tools->Internet Options->Security tab, click on “Custom Level” button.
>   Find the Miscellaneous -> Access data sources across domains setting
>   and select “Enable” option.

Sure enough, when I enable this setting, the request goes through and everything works as it should. However, I've read that this setting is not actually related to CORS and *shouldn't* affect it. When using [this tool](https://test-cors.appspot.com/#technical) to test for CORS compatibility, IE10 passes regardless of whether this setting is enabled or disabled, which leads me to believe CORS *is* enabled and I'm just doing something wrong.

Also, everything seems to work as it should when I run [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/), since Fiddler is acting as a proxy.

For reference, here's the CORS-related code on the server side:

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "example.com");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization, X-File-Name, X-File-Size, X-File-Type");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
if (req.method == "OPTIONS") {
 res.send(200);
}
```

Comment: First of all, a wildcard is not allowed in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header for any credentialed cross-origin requests.  This is likely not your problem, but this may get you into trouble later.  If you don't intend to support credentialed CORS, then remove the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header from your response.  If you do want to support credentialed CORS, you will have to target specific domains in your Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header.

Comment: @RayNicholus: Thanks for the comment. I've been trying everything I can think of – I originally had a specific domain there but apparently a wildcard was the last thing I tried before writing this question.

Comment: Please share the relevant request's headers along with the response headers according to IE10.  This may provide more useful evidence.

Comment: There are no headers to inspect. The request is being blocked by IE before it's even being sent.

Comment: This is not a CORS issue then.

Comment: @RayNicholus: I've updated my question quite a bit to include some more information. I'm sure this has something to do with CORS, but I suppose posting the server-side code wasn't really relevant considering the request doesn't seem to be sending...

Comment: You can install [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to observe the traffic, compare the browsers to see if anything is sent at all. Are there any special request headers set?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be sending any requests to the API. There are two API-related requests and both are being blocked. It's not even attempting to send an OPTIONS request. I'm installing Fiddler to see if I can get more information than what IE10 is giving me.

Comment: With Fiddler running, the requests get made (because Fiddler is acting as proxy) but the response body is still empty. The API is over SSL and I'm on a virtual machine – might this have anything to do with it?

Comment: @RayNicholus: I've added to my question quite a bit. Would you mind taking a second look?

Comment: @jakub.g: I've added to my question quite a bit. Would you mind taking a second look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try sending the request to the API server using HTTP instead of HTTPS.  The issue sounds like it may have to do with the server's SSL settings more so than the request itself. If this is the case try using SSL settings to something like this.

```
var options = {
  key:    fs.readFileSync(key),
  cert:   fs.readFileSync(certificate),
  ca:     fs.readFileSync(CA),
  requestCert:        false,
};

https.createServer(options, app).listen(443);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, finally to make things easier I did a nginx proxy_pass directive 
So I made http://example.com/api point to http://api.example.com
Then in the javascript code will request to example.com/api and the browser will not complain.

I know that this is not ideal, but not all browser support CORS in the same way, especially IE. 
When you want to give support all the browsers the proxy_pass option is the simplest way.

In other case you'll be making changes to make things work in IE and breaking other browsers support.
Not saying that it's impossible, but it will take more testing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I hadn't thought of using `proxy_pass`. If all else fails, then I'll probably go this route. However, CORS in IE10 *should* work the same way as other modern browsers – I can't help but think that I'm doing something else wrong...

Comment: @DavidJones I know it's a while back but did you ever find a solution to this? I'm struggling with a similar issue with IE10.

Answer (score 0):

To get my CORS request to work in IE, I had to make my call like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: apiRoot + "/endpoint",
  xhrFields: {
     withCredentials: true
  },
  crossDomain: true,
  success: function(response) {
    // Omitted irrelevant code
  }
});
```