# What are the differences between CORS for IE10 and Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors

I wrote a CORS request using jQuery, which is as simple as:

```
var BJS = {Services: {} };

BJS.Services.GetDatasources = function (data, success, fail) {
    if (data == null) data = {};
    var u = data["user"],
        p = data["pass"],
        url = data["url"],
        ext = data["ext"],
        secure = data["secure"] ? "https://" : "http://",
        up = BJS.Base64.encode(u + ":" + p),
        d = data["data"] ? data["data"] : "";
    $.ajax({
        url: secure + url + ext,
        data: d,
        headers: {
            Authorization: "Basic " + up
        },
        success: success,
        error: fail
    });
};
```

This request works perfectly in Chrome.  In IE, it returns an error:

```
 Error: Access is denied.

     at send (...)
     at ajax (...)
     at GetDatasources (...)
     at eval code (eval code:1:1)
     at Global code (Unknown script code:5:1)
```

which to me points to the $.ajax request i believe.

Is there a different way i should handle this ajax request?  Are different variables needed?

I was hoping that jQuery's $.ajax call would abstract away from the Browser dependencies, to allow a more uniform functionality across browsers, but alas, this is not the case here.

**Edit:**  For security, i removed the tags, but all the variables DID in fact have default values:  example:

```
u = data["user"] || "admin";
```

but i wanted to remove the hashs, url, etc from the outside world.

**Edit**  No one has posted any answers, but i would like to show a workaround that i have done for people curious, but the root question is still not answered.

```
$.support.cors = true
if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) >= 8 && XDomainRequest) {
    //IE
    //using a webservice will remove the cors, and you can just forward the response to the client.
    //it takes up some processing time, but this is the workaround i accomplish.
    $.ajax({url: "webservice.svc"});  //this can be a .php file, or anything really that runs ont he server.

}else{
    //chrome/ff
    //call page as normal.
    $.ajax({url:"resource_file"});
}
```

Comment: What are the CORS headers that the server is sending back?

Comment: When i run it in code it just executes the error.  Monitoring the network does not show any requests.  If i execute the request in console:  IF Tool>Internet Options>CustomLevel>Misc>Allow Cross Origin> ENABLED.   It will return a success.

It is by default disabled, which returns an error.  Slowing reading through: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422980/security-error-using-cors-in-ie10-with-node-and-express

Comment: that link says that it should be able to work successfully even if disabled, but it is odd how when running the program as is, it doesnt even post anything to the Network tab of the DevTools.

Comment: You're not running in compatibility mode are you? I'd expect IE10 to handle cors just like the rest of the modern browsers since it implements XHR2. If it's in compatibility mode you'll need to patch in CORS support because jQuery doesn't really support CORS requests in IE<10.

Comment: Since i do not how to check, i just did:  navigator.userAgent, which returned:  "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0E)"

Comment: When you're in the debugging console in IE10, there's a selector on the top where you can select which browser mode you want to run in.

Comment: I just noticed this, yes, Browser Mode:   is just IE10, not compatibility, or any older browsers.