# AJAX or XHR with credentials not working in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, cors

I'm currently stuck on some CORS problems in IE. My googling has left me with the understanding of IE + CORS = trouble.

I have this piece of code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "URL",
  crossDomain: true,
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
  },
  success: function() {
    //Handle success
  },
  error: function(error){
    //Handle error
  }
});
```

which works perfect in Chrome, Firefox and Vivaldi, but NOT in IE 11...

The problem is: If I have incorrect or I don't have any credentials stored under `Control Panel\User Accounts\Credential Manager` Chrome, Firefox and Vivaldi triggers a dialog where I can type in username and password. This is not the case in Internet Explorer. Allthough if I open the same URL in a normal tab, the dialog appears.

[image: Authentication dialog]

The console prints out these two errors:
`SEC7120: Origin "URL" not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.`
and
`SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.`

And as the title explains: I do have tried with regular XMLHTTPRequest, with exactly the same results.

Hence my questions:

- Is it possible to trigger this dialog through JavaScript?
- Is it possible to overwrite/change credentials through JavaScript? Wouldn't this be a huge security issue if it's possible?
- What kind of magic does all other browsers do with the request that IE does not?
- Any other possibilities?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Security error using CORS in IE10 with Node and Express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422980/security-error-using-cors-in-ie10-with-node-and-express)