# overrideMimeType alternative for IE

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

This is a question that never has a proper answer, i have search the net many times and i couldnt find a solution.

```
xhr.open("GET", fullurl, true);
if(xhr.overrideMimeType) xhr.overrideMimeType("text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");
xhr.send(null);

xhr.onreadystatechange  = function(){ 
if(xhr.readyState  == 4){
if(xhr.status  == 200) 
alert(xhr.responseText);
```

It works for firefox, chrome. My responseText will return char like Réunion, which will appear as weird symbols.

I tried many methods like encoding and decoding, setting header in response file which does not work. i'm out of ideas. Please help somebody.

---

```
**SOLUTION**
```

In your main file, make sure you set your content type and charset.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

In your AJAX-loaded page, make sure you have this at the top.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');
```

Problem solved, your a happy man. this is no longer needed.

```
if(xhr.overrideMimeType) xhr.overrideMimeType("text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");
```

Comment: I don't think this works any more...hope I am wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need anything fancy like overrideMimeType. Just make sure the encodings of your main and AJAX-loaded page are correct (preferrably UTF-8 for both). Most likely, you have forgotten the [meta tag](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#attr-meta-http-equiv-content-type) declaring the encoding.

Comment: Use HTTP headers, they have high precedence then meta equivs, and don't restart parsing if the browser realizes it was using the wrong encoding.

Comment: are you asking me to set <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /></head> at both my main and ajax-loaded page? if yes, after setting it, my main page also having same problem, and the ajax result is still the same. please advise

Comment: i'm sorry but that fixed the problem but my charset needed would be iso-8859-1. Thankyou very much

Answer (score 0):

I can't change the encoding with the meta tag and access to the server. In IE I access the responseBody to create a responseText with the correct chars. 
Here is my answer :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22030309/3353928