# is there a cross-browser alternative to the xhr.overrideMimeType() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I don't have access to the server and I need that the whole AJAX transaction to happen using the ISO-8859-1 charset. I'm using the jQuery.load() function together with the following jQuery method:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({'beforeSend' : function(xhr) {xhr.overrideMimeType('charset=ISO-8859-15'); }});
```

even though firefox and chrome are returning the results correctly encoded, IE (all versions) are not. Is there any way to fix it only at the client-side?

p.s. All the content is correctly encoded in ISO-8859-1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had a similar problem but the issue is basically that 'overrideMimeType' is not supported in IE (any version). So basically you need to do something like in the following articles:

[jQuery, AJAX and Internet Explorer](http://jeremyhixon.com/jquery-ajax-internet-explorer/#.T5DXFKtSTjI) by Jeremy Hixon or this [question here in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850765/overridemimetype-alternative-for-ie)

Hope this helps.