# Binary data in the browser

Tags: javascript

I'm using `.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');` on my `XMLHttpRequest` object to load a binary datafile into javascript. I'm able to get the data byte by byte with `data.charCodeAt(pos) & 0xff;`

This works great in FF and Chrome (The two browsers I've tested so far). I've not yet tested Safari - but I would guess that it will work. Everything I've read is that IE (including 9) and Opera do not support this.

For IE is there any alternative I can use? An ActiveX control possibly?
Is there an alternative in Opera that I can use?

Comment: "Everything I've read is that IE (including 9) and Opera do not support this." Did you actually test it?

Answer (score 1):

I had to use some VBScript to get it to work.

See [how do I access XHR responseBody (for binary data) from Javascript in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919972/how-do-i-access-xhr-responsebody-from-javascript)