# How do I access 8-bit binary data from Javascript in Opera?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, opera, xmlhttprequest-level2

This question is an extension of [this StackOverflow question about IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919972/how-do-i-access-xhr-responsebody-for-binary-data-from-javascript-in-ie) to the Opera 12 browser.

The root problem is an [issue in geoxml3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/issues/detail?id=63) handling kmz (zipped kml) files.

[Example that fails in Opera 12](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmztest_linkto.html)

The binary data is being processed with TypedArrays in a [modified version of ZipFile.complete.js](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/source/browse/branches/kmz/ZipFile.complete.js)

After the binary file is transferred the Uint8Array is not populated correctly in Opera 12, it is as if the data is being imported as 16-bit elements.

The request is configured like this:

```
this.req.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
this.req.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
```

The value returned is handled like this:

```
var fileContents = binStream.req.response;
binStream.length = fileContents.byteLength;
binStream.array = new Uint8Array(fileContents);
```

the first eight bytes are populated like this in Opera 12:

0x004B0050; giving a decimal value of 4915280

but should be:

0x4034B50; a decimal value of 67324752.

This works correctly in Firefox, Chrome and IE (with a workaround).

Does anyone know how I can convince Opera 12 to populate the Uint8Array correctly?  Or a workaround so that it will work (some way to convert the array of 16-bit bytes into an array of 8-bit bytes, discarding the unneeded upper 8-bits as efficiently as possible)?  Is this a known bug in the recent implementation of the TypedArray/XmlHttpRequest in Opera 12?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Opera 12.00 introduced support for `responseType`; unfortunately, there's a bug in it that means given a `text/*` MIME type you'll end up the file as 16-bit words. It's fixed in 12.01, but the simplest fix is to set the override type as `application/octet-stream`. (This is CORE-46938 for those of you desiring to stalk a closed bug-tracker.)

Comment: setting the MIME type to application/octet-stream does fix the problem in Opera 12 (I must have changed it in the wrong place the first time, I will delete the comment that says it doesn't work). This was what I changed: this.req.overrideMimeType('application/octet-stream; charset=x-user-defined');

Comment: @geocodezip See the [Desktop Team Blog](http://my.opera.com/desktopteam/blog/) or [Opera Next](http://www.opera.com/browser/next/) for 12.01 builds. Release date unknown.

Answer (score 2):

This "patch" works:

```
var fileContents = binStream.req.response;
binStream.length = fileContents.byteLength;
binStream.array = new Uint8Array(fileContents);

/* patch for Opera */
if (/opera/i.test(navigator.userAgent) && 
    // make sure it is still broken,
    // the first 4 bytes will contain the zip file signature
    // for the geoxml3 use case (so bytes 1 & 3 will not be 0)
    (binStream.array[1] == 0) && (binStream.array[3] == 0))
{    
    fixedArray = new Uint8Array(binStream.length/2);
    for (var i=0; i<binStream.length; i+=2) {
        fixedArray[i/2]=binStream.array[i];
    }
    binStream.array = fixedArray;
    binStream.length = binStream.length/2;
}
/* end patch for Opera */
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?  Does anyone know a way to do it without doing the browser specific test?

EDIT: added check to make sure the behavior is still broken (in case it is a bug and is fixed).  May not work in the general case, but for the geoxml3 use case the first 4 bytes will contain the zip file signature which will not have 0's in the high order bytes if it works correctly.