# How to save array of bytes (xmlhttprequest.responseBody) from a url of zip file and save it locally?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I want to download a zip file from a url as binary array using `XMLHttpRequest.responseBody` and then save it as a file. How can I do that?

I am using IE 8 and have reached till receving the `xmlhttprequest.responsebody` and convert it to text format.

[how do I access XHR responseBody (for binary data) from Javascript in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919972/how-do-i-access-xhr-responsebody-for-binary-data-from-javascript-in-ie)

but what then? how do I save these array of bytes as file?

I am quite new to javascript and php.

```
function httpPost1(theUrl,param)
{

  var xmlHttp = null;

  xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xmlHttp.open( "POST", theUrl+"?"+param, true);
  xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Accept-Charset", "x-user-defined");

  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange =function(){

        if(xmlHttp.readyState==4)
     {   
           if(xmlHttp.status==200)
        {           
           // convert to string format from resonse
           var fileContents = convertResponseBodyToText(xmlHttp.responseBody);
           var bresults =[];  // convert to sring response to array of integers
           for (var i=0; i<fileContents.length; i++)
             {
           bresults[i] =fileContents.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff
             }

             // how will i save the array as file?
         }

          }
        }
    xmlHttp.send();
}
```

As I am using with older versions of IE8, use of `FileAPI`, `FileReader`, `FileWriter` nothing worked.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why not simply let the user download the file?

Comment: well, the scenario is quite different here.The downloading URL is of a local system in the client LAN. So once I have recieved the binary data using xhr, I want to save it at the server system(using jscript) or directly upload the binary data to PHP script which might be able to save it as file.