# ie9 javascript download function doesn´t work

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I've created new download function using JS for IE9, but it doesn't work.

```
descargarArchivo : function (url, idlote) {
            var str = window.location.href+"/"+url;
            str = str.replace("form.do/", "");
            // Le da nombre del fichero que se va a descargar
            var filename = 'factura_'+idlote;
            xhr= new XMLHttpRequest(); 
            xhr.responseType = 'blob';
            xhr.onload = function() {
                      var a = document.createElement('a');
                      a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response); 
                      a.download = filename; // Set the file name.
                      a.style.display = 'none';
                      document.body.appendChild(a);                         
                      a.click();
                      delete a;
                  }
               } 
           };
           xhr.open('GET', str);
           xhr.send();
        }
```

I read that, in IE9 there is no Blob type, so `xhr.response` returns undefined. How can I resolve it?

Comment: Did you search for a solution on stackoverflow, seems like this would have been asked already? IE9 Blob Polyfill

Comment: Yes, but I there are a lot of questions without answers.

Comment: Well you could not use Ajax instead submit a form and have the server set the download headers.

Comment: You should add more precisions to your question then. Is your file always a PDF?

Comment: No. My file is html or xml.

Comment: Can I use different type than 'Blob' to download a file?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1926163/2435443

He uses injected VBScript *(ActiveXObject)* to convert byte strings to binary array, it's a kind of Blob 'emulation' without the object definition. Looks fast & robust.